# Paypal testing credit card in Sandbox Mode only USA & GB?

Tags: android, paypal

I have integrated the paypal sdk into my android app. So far everything is working fine. When paypal open I can choose pay with paypal or pay with credit card in sandbox mode.

Pay with paypal is working fine and I get the result code in onActivityResult.

But if I choose pay with credit card and enter a dummy credit card number then I get the button "charge credit card" and nothing happens if I push the button.

Is this behavior normal? Normally I should get a result code back too on onActivityResult ?

So I don't know at the moment if pay with credit card is working in live environment too.

Answer (score 0):

For testing the pay with credit card feature while in Sandbox mode, you have a couple of options. You may either go into your Sandbox "buyer" profile under funding and use the credit card number from the funding source there or you may use any test card number. A great site for valid test credit card numbers is www.getcreditcardnumbers.com and you may use any expiration date and CSC code. The cards from the site I mentioned will always give you a decline.

Comment: Hi thanx for your answer but i have still the save problem in sandbox mode. even if i enter the credit card number from the profile then i get the message confirm payment ...charge credit card and after pushing the button it goes back to main menu where i can choose paypal payment/pay with credit card ..it does not go back to my checkout activity . i don´t know where the problem is

Comment: Are you trying to do Express Checkout or direct credit card payments?

Comment: direct credit card payment without logging in to the paypal sandbox account. on android it gives me the options either to pay with paypal or to enter a credit card number

Comment: Are you using the mobile SDK?

Comment: I would call PayPal and be sure you have approval for credit card processing. I think there may also be an issue with the redirect. Could you post the code for the redirect portion?

Comment: there is no special code i have used ..just the normal examples by paypal . also my account on developer.paypal.com says that credit cart processing is enabled in sandbox mode

Answer (score 0):

Hey Frank it works all over the  world because i'm working on it from Asia.
There was actually some issues in paypal sdk 2.9.10 Paypal sdk version 2.9.11 is working fine with credit card payments. You can download the Paypal sdk version 2.9.11 from the link below.
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK